# Belongingness vs Social Connectedness

Tags: social-psychology, motivation, social-networks

I am struggling with translation of these two words into my language. In many studies, they measure connectedness (or how much people feel connected) or belongingness (as need to belong or sense of belongingness). I have been searching for definitions and based on my research of definitions and contexts (see below for examples) it can be concluded that it is the same thing. Is it correct?

For example:

- Belongingness is the human emotional need to be an accepted member of
  a group. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belongingness)
- Social connectedness is defined as the sense of belonging and
  subjective psychological bond that people feel in relation to
  individuals and groups of others (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/302472164_Social_Connectedness_and_Health)
- Social connectedness, i.e. the experience of belonging and
  relatedness between people (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220992602_Social_connectedness_Concept_and_measurement)
- The study developed 2 measures of belongingness based on H. Kohut's (1984) self psychology theory. The Social Connectedness Scale and the Social Assurance Scale were constructed.....(http://psycnet.apa.org/record/1995-23687-001)